# Hibernate:How to create-drop schema manually?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I want to create-drop tables(my db is postgresql) after every junit test. i have tried spring's @Transactional with no luck (i guess since i am using transactions inside the code some how they overlap and stuff) so i deiced to take a bit hacky way. this is the code that i am using at @Before and expecting the hibernate to create-drop at each test

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

    MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
    MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder = metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder();

    SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport((MetadataImplementor) metadataBuilder.build());
    export.setFormat(true);
    export.create(true,true);
```

the operation respond as a success but nothing really happens.
any help will be appreciated.

Note that i have set the hbm2dll to create(i have also tried with create-drop:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you are running your tests with a SpringContext, the solution that worked for me is: [DirtiesContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html). With this annotation you are explicitly stating that your test had made some changes in your context (including database) that have the potential to affect other tests. So Spring will discard this context and create a brand-new to the next test. This solution combined with a `create-drop` config in your Hibernate will result in the DB getting recreated every time you need.

*Note:
Rebuilding the DB (or the context) is time-consuming. You should try to avoid using this for all your test if you can. Purging your DB and then recreating it hundreds of times can increase the time required to run all your tests significantly.*

Comment: thanks for comment. i will check DirtiesContext and come back with results. the ideal way to handle this situation is to use rollbacks which unfortunately is not working for my situation.

Comment: i wonder how do you know it :D i searched a lot but didn't find @Dirtiescontext

Comment: Good colleagues. :) I do not even even remember which one of us found it first, but now it is used each time when we do something slightly hacky to the DB in a test. I am happy that it worked for you.